# Filter @domain.edu from dataset in R

Tags: r

I have an email list, like the following:

```
emails <- c("john.doe@ivyleague.edu", "education@world.gov", "dalai.lama@peace.org", "invalid.edu", "quant@bigdatacollege.edu", "cookie.monster@sesame.tv")
```

I need to select only mails that are from a .edu domain.

I have this code:

```
edu_emails <- c()
for (email in emails) {
  end <- substr(email, nchar(email)-2, nchar(email))
  if (end == "edu") {
    edu_emails <- c(edu_emails, email)
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem efficient, do you know a better system to do it?

Comment: You can use `endsWith`: `endsWith(emails, '.edu')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R provides integrated methods to perform these tasks, such as [`grepl`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep).

Here I show you an example:

```
# The emails vector
emails <- c("john.doe@ivyleague.edu", "education@world.gov", "dalai.lama@peace.org",
            "invalid.edu", "quant@bigdatacollege.edu", "cookie.monster@sesame.tv")

# Use grepl() to match for .edu addresses more robustly
grepl("@.*\\.edu$", emails)

# Use grep() to match for .edu addresses more robustly, save result to hits
hits <- grep("@.*\\.edu$", emails)

# Subset emails using hits
emails[hits]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, I didn't know this method

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`

```
grep("@.*\\.edu$", emails, value = TRUE)
#[1] "john.doe@ivyleague.edu"   "quant@bigdatacollege.edu"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, I didn't know this method

Comment: I up-voted you, but the solution step by step is more comfortable for me

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str_subset` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_subset(emails, '@.*\\.edu$')
#[1] "john.doe@ivyleague.edu"   "quant@bigdatacollege.edu"
```

This is similar to `stringi`'s `stri_subset_regex`

```
stringi::stri_subset_regex(emails, '@.*\\.edu$')
```